# Python - Django - cardav - How to implement a server

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, caldav

I have a server application written with Django which has a contacts database.

I wish to add a cardav webservice in order to share my contacts on my phone. I have made many search but I am completely lost.

I found some server as Radical, some API which uses files ... but nothing help me.

I need to implement in my server an API which will return to my Android the list of contact from my databases. What output format should I use ?

Thank you.

Comment: I agree with hnh, Radicale is a good starting point for CardDAV & Python. AFAIK they have a modular backend that also supports loading & storing contacts from/to a SQL database. So you could just attach it to your database instead of writing a new implementation from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems a bit generic nor do you list what resources you looked at and why you are lost.

[This presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzgomnabxdM) is a little old, but shows the fundamentals on how the *DAV protocols work. [Building a CardDAV Client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-carddav-client/) is another great starting point.

CardDAV itself is specified in
[RFC 6352](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352), and the related RFCs:
[WebDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918),
[WebDAV ACL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3744),
etc.

> What output format should I use ?

CardDAV requests and responses use
[WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV),
hence XML.
The actual payload is a
[vCard v3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#vCard_3.0).

If you are looking for sample code:
The [Apple CalendarServer](http://calendarserver.org)
is a full-fledged CalDAV/CardDAV server written in Python.
Radicale is another one, but you already found that (be more specific why this isn't helping you, Radicale looks like a great starting point to me).

Finally: I don't think Android has CardDAV support builtin. Presumably you are using a sync plugin?